# How to ensure readiness of container replicas in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and I was wondering if it is possible to have container replicas launching one at a time? In other words, if I deploy a compose file yielding a container or pod configuration with N replicas, is it possible (and if so how) to ensure that each replica waits for the previous one to be ready before launching?

I read about readiness probes, but if I understood them correctly, they ensure pod ordering instead of replica, or did I misunderstood?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[A StatefulSet has this property](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees): given three replicas, the second one will not start until the first one is running and ready.

(Usually "replica" and "pod" mean the same thing.  If you create a Deployment or StatefulSet with 3 replicas, and run `kubectl get pods` once it's done, you should see 3 pods.)

If you're using Kompose to do the deployment, there's at least [a hint that it doesn't support StatefulSets](http://kompose.io/user-guide/#alternative-conversions); you need to write native Kubernetes YAML for this.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has the StatefulSet Object to manage a set of replica's of a Pod. The StatefulSet differs from the default Deployment in the sense that it provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods. From [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees):

> For a StatefulSet with N replicas, when Pods are being deployed, they are created sequentially, in order from {0..N-1}.

As an example, [see this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes) on how to setup a StatefulSet for ElasticSearch.

Comment: Hi @Blokje5 thanks for the reply, but I do not see how this answers my question. Can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: You were talking about a rolling update of your Pods right, i.e. you want to update a set of containers with x replica's one at a time? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: just a simple deployment

Comment: You want to guarentee an ordering in the rollout of your replica's? i.e. replica 2 needs to start running as soon as replica 1 is finished? Is that your question?

Comment: Just to be clear: i) the compose file defines an application with the replicas field set to e.g. 3; ii) I deploy my compose file; iii) replica 2 waits for replica 1 to be up and running before launching; iv) replica 3 wait for replica 2 to be up and running before launching.

Comment: Great, then I understand your question. I might have an answer, let me edit my post